# How to call the Dynamics 365 OData endpoint to get a list of users from Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi, odata, dynamics-365, delphi-10.2-tokyo

If I authenticate to D365 via the web browser, and then enter the following URL:

*https://**mytenantcode**.**crmserver**.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/systemusers?$select=systemuserid,lastname,firstname,title&$top=3*

I can get back the top 3 records with the data I requested.

I seem to be able to authenticate to D365 in code as per [my other question](https://stackoverflow**.com/questions/49310503/how-to-connect-a-delphi-desktop-app-to-a-third-party-dynamics-365-app-using-oaut) (which I answered), and have an access token but I cannot seem to be able to determine how to setup the `TRESTRequest` object so that the Execute works.

Currently, it always returns a **401 Unauthorized** error.

I've tried setting the `TOAuth2Authenticator.AccessToken` property to the token I received from D365, and then set the `TRESTClient.Authenticator` property to the `TOAuth2Authenticator` and the `TRESTQuest.Client` to the `TRESTClient`, which is how the examples work in the *RESTDemos* project, but I still get **401**.

This is the last example of the code I tried, that should have worked, given that all the REST objects are linked correctly:

```
  RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://**mytenantcode**.**crmserver**.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/';

  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
  RESTRequest.Resource := 'systemusers?$select={SELECT}&$top={TOP}';

  RESTRequest.AddParameter('SELECT', 'systemuserid,'+
                                      'lastname,'+
                                      'firstname,'+
                                      'title');
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('TOP', '3');

  RESTRequest.Execute;
```

Comment: There is this question on the Dynamics forum which seems similar, and the answer is that Dynamics 365 doesn't support it outside of ADAL. https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/256722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to return the correct information using the following code for calling the Web API:

```
  RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://mytenantcode.crmserver.dynamics.com/';

  RESTRequest.Resource := 'api/data/v8.2/systemusers?$select=int_staffnumber,'+
                                                            '_int_serviceareaid_value,'+
                                                            '_territoryid_value,'+
                                                            'lastname,'+
                                                            'firstname,'+
                                                            'systemuserid,'+
                                                            'title';

  RESTRequest.AddAuthParameter('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + AToken, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER,
    [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]);

  RESTRequest.Execute;
```

The important change was the addition of the Authorization header parameter, and not using the Params for the query parameters as it seems the REST Client Library doesn't actually do it correctly.

Also had to change the ResourceURI for the token authorization to match the *https://**mytenantcode.crmserver**.dynamics.com* URL being used for the method call.